# simple wordpress cart plugin

Tags: wordpress, shopping-cart, cart

I know there are plenty checkout plugins out there but to be honest - they are so extended and huge.. I am looking for something really simple:
+ I have category like COOKIES and subpages there which are my products
+ on product page after description should be only button add to cart (plus No of ordered items -> if plugin do not have it, no problem )
+ after clicking on checkout button you can only give the simple data like email, address, name.

No payments, no taxes.. only sending such ordering on my email. do you know anything like that?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming problems. Start by reading the [FAQ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy to setup and should fit the bill

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-e-commerce/